# Usability of colour pickers in HSL format compared to RGB and HEX

Tags: usability, gui-design, colours

Reading a recent article about [HSL colour pickers](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/hsl-a-color-format-for-humans/) being more user-friendly, I thought about the reason why the RGB and HEX colour pickers exist and who they are catering for, and it seems quite obvious that these types of colour pickers are created by and for designers and developers because this is the convention and way that we have been specifying colours since the early days of the web. It is in contrast to the CMYK colour palettes that people who work in the physical print medium as opposed to the digital medium.

But since there is so much focus on self-publishing on the web, and more tools to allow the everyday designer and developer to contribute to the plethora of sites that already exist (and we need to if we want to move towards web 3.0 and beyond where everyone is an owner and contributor), it is interesting that the HSL colour pickers are not getting the popularity that it probably could be getting.

From a UX designer perspective, isn't the HSL colour picker more user friendly for the general users (and even designers)?

Is there a particular reason (other than the fact that RGB and HEX colour pickers make up the overwhelming majority) that HSL colour pickers shouldn't be more popular?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single answer to this question—it largely depends on the purpose of the colour being selected, and the relationship between the picker's starting value and the user's desired one.

[Most colour pickers I've ever seen use some variety of slice through HSL colour space as a starting point for selecting an arbitrary colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Use_in_end-user_software), even those without dedicated H/S/L sliders in place. The utility of H/S/L sliders themselves come down to how important it is to select a specific colour, or how important it is to be able to easily adjust a given colour in a specific way.

I suspect the most valuable kind of colour picker UI is an array of basic colours as an option, which I suspect meets a lot of user requirements (allowing the user to select "orange" or "green" very quickly).

Major commercial colour pickers almost always featured those, like the Microsoft Paint one:

[image: Microsoft Paint colour picker]
<sup>Image taken from [Digital Inspiration](https://www.labnol.org/home/hue-saturation-luminosity/20104/)</sup>

…and the Mac (née NextStep) colour picker:

[image: macOS colour picker showing its Pencils view]

…and the default colour picker in Safari:

[image: Safari colour picker]

Apple's new [UIColorPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorpickerviewcontroller) iOS control also has it (called "Grid" view), and Office tools also default to this view.

Despite the long list of tools making the choice of a basic colour very simple, Chrome appears to be the outlier, showing a comparatively very complicated colour picker without any grid of starting colours, such that users must do quite a lot more work to select "orange". It also provides no clear feedback about the range of valid values for each field to users who don't already know:

[image: Chrome colour picker]

Comment: +1 A very solid and well explained answer as usual! Haven't heard much from the UX community in Australia during the pandemic but nice to hear from you again :)